# cannot get "hg log file" to display anything

Tags: mercurial

I want to find out which change sets have modifications to a file called WRAPPER.CPP.

I have tried "hg log [relative_path_to_file]WRAPPER.CPP"

I have tried changing directories to [relative_path_to_file] and then "hg log WRAPPER.CPP"

Neither gives me any output.

I am on Windows.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the tab key to auto-complete the path at the command line? No output at all from log kind of indicates that it can't find the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial is case sensitive.  Are you sure the case on the file name as you're entering the command matches how it's actually committed?  "hg manifest" should help you check.